# How do I jump in Impossible Mission for Apple ][

Tags: impossible-mission

I can't figure out how to jump Impossible Mission for Apple ][. It happens sometimes, but when I try, no particular key I press while running makes the player jump.

How do I make it jump?

[image]

Comment: I take it you've tried the space bar and up arrow key? Those are pretty much the only two I can think of.

Comment: I think I've tried pretty much every key, but I'll try again. I'm starting to think it's some key combo.

Answer (score 2):

You have to press the joystick Fire button (Keyboard: Space Bar or Enter when I played) to jump.  If you're in the "Aisle" mode, you have to be moving left or right.

If you press Fire while standing still in the Aisle (where you can see the pocket computer at the bottom of the screen), you'll toggle the cursor in the pocket computer instead.

Comment: Space or Enter didn't work for me, but I had selected "no" when asked if I have a joystick. I use 'j' for left, 'i' for up (it doesn't work for jumping, too), and 'l' for right, and 'm' for down.

Comment: @sashoalm, I tried it today in an online Apple 2 emulator and it worked, so I don't know what to tell you...

Comment: I finally found out the key - it was **Alt**.